# Creating new object using an existing object with HandlerInterceptorAdapter

Tags: java, json, spring

I wanted all my exceptions to be logged. I thought thought that adding `Logger.error` to every method would solve my problem, but luckily I discovered `HandlerInterceptorAdapter` and saved time!

Now I don't want to return "regular" objects, but to return an object that contains other objects and exceptions. The reason is that in this way, I won't get `HTTP Status 500`, but get an object containing the exception.

Basically:
If my service would return normally - return an object containing the returned object.
If my service would return with an exception - return an object that has the children up to the exception, and the exception that caused the problem.

I hoped that using `HandlerInterceptorAdapter` would be easy, but I was mistaken...

In a regular service - 
If I look at postHandle: `modelAndView` is null.

In both `postHandle` and `afterCompletion` using `response.getWriter().write(s)` raises

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] threw exception 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
```

`response.getHeaderNames()` contains only [Content-Type, Transfer-Encoding, Date].

I don't know what to do with `response.getOutputStream().`

Using `request`/`handler` gets me to no where also.

What can I do?

Comment: You are using the wrong tool... For handling exceptions spring has the `HandlerExceptionResolver`.

Comment: My exceptions are handled good. I need to parse the returned value.